# MVC 5 calling the wrong create function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Firstly I am still pretty new to MVC.

Model -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace PT.Models {
    public class Test {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestsDBContext : DbContext {
        public DbSet<Test> Tests { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View (Create) -

```
@model PT.Models.Test

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Test</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Controller (Just create functions) -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using PT.Models;

namespace PT.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        private TestsDBContext db = new TestsDBContext();

        // GET: /Test/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: /Test/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="Id,Name")] Test test)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Tests.Add(test);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(test);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

When I go to http : //.../Test/Create, enter the required fields and click "Create", I am directed to the first Create function(without parameters). Why doesn't it go to the function that passes in the Test object?

EDIT: I also noticed that although the name field isn't required, I continue to get a "The Name field is required" error when I click Create.

Also, it might help that I am on VS 2012, having installed MVC 5.

Comment: Your code is fine. Put a break point on the first line `if (ModelState.IsValid)` of the post method and check its being hit.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - that's exactly what I did and why I know it doesn't get to that function.

Comment: I just copied you code into my project (removing all the db stuff) and it works fine. You must have another problem. Check the html rendered for the `form` tag. It should be `<form action="/test/create" method="post">`

Comment: @StephenMuecke - I am using @ using (Html.BeginForm()) and I don't know where to put those attributes.

Comment: I know your using `BeginForm`. What I am saying is check the actual html that is rendered (view the page source) ang check the form tag has the attributes as mentioned in my last comment (your usage of `BeginForm` should render those by default)

Comment: As far as the error message goes, yes it is required because its typeof `int` which must have a value, so if you do not enter anything then validation fails. I suspect property `Name` really should be `string` not `int`. And the fact you are getting this error message only proves that your code is correct and it will hit the POST action.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I came to the same conclusion. It might really be a `string` instead of an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

By default, actions supports `POST` request so it is the case for your first `Create` action. So my guess is that it is chosen over the second one. Try to add `[HttpGet]` attribute to your first action so that it only accepts `GET` requests.

**Edit**

If the code you've given is the same you use, then it might come from the fact that you declared the `Name` property as an `int` and you were filling the form with a non integer string.

Comment: @duckmike I've tried your code and as Stephen Muecke it works fine. So as he said it might come from somewhere else.